# Text in div has background color

Tags: html, image, imagebackground

If I put a text element in a div element, the text shows another background color than the div element. Bellow is a picture and the code

Thank you

```css
.category {
        background-color: brown;
        width: 350px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .category h2 {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="category">
   <h2>Rain</h2>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: working fine, effect on other CSS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here it works, but not in mine project